# i need help for login page

Tags: javascript, html

I need help for a login page using JavaScript. So far I have following code:

```
function clicked() {

var user = document.getElementById('username');
var pass = document.getElementById('password');

var coruser = "admin";
var corpass = "admin";

if (user.value == coruser) {

    if (pass.value == corpass) {

        // Like you must login to see the page

    } else {
        window.alert("incorrect password or name");
    }
} else {
    window.alert("incorrect password or name");
}
}
```

I want it like after login show the page like you must login to see the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not secure, any one can see your username and password when viewing the source of your site.

Comment: i know i don't need security but can i find helpful?

Comment: You can store sign up info in `localStorage` and then use that information to log back in. However, the correct way to do javascript sessions is using something like [Backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org). It looks like you are new at this and my advice is to work in stepping stones. A first good setup would be to learn jQuery and then maybe build a Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should look like this if you want to redirect user to your home page after checking the username.

```
function clicked() {

var user = document.getElementById('username');
var pass = document.getElementById('password');

var coruser = "admin";
var corpass = "admin";

if (user.value == coruser) {
    if (pass.value == corpass) {
        window.location.href = "your page url";
    } else {
    window.alert("incorrect password or name");
 }
} else {
    window.alert("incorrect password or name");
}
}
```

Note: this is not a way to  handle authentication.